# Credentials aren't allowed error when using Outlook REST API Oauth2 in AWS server

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to implement Outlook Oauth2 in our Django backend server which is hosted on an AWS instance.

I carefully followed the instructions in their [python tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/python-tutorial) and it works **100% in my local machine**. I am able to grab the `authorization code` which I then convert in my backend server to an `access token`.

The problem lies in our demo server which is an AWS instance. We have a button that redirects the users to Outlook authentication. The URL has the following format:

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<client-ID-here>&redirect_uri=<demo-server-redirect-url>&response_type=code&scope=openid+profile+offline_access+Calendars.ReadWrite&prompt=consent`

I am receiving the following error whenever I convert the `authorization code` into an `access token` just after the consent screen:

```
{
    'error': 'access_denied',
    'error_description': 'Your credentials aren't allowed'
}
```

The weird thing is that if I use **POSTMAN** using the demo server Outlook credentials, I am able to retrieve an `access token` from Outlook.

Basically, it works for both in my local machine and using Postman. I really think that I'm just missing a very small piece of code/configuration here. Are there some extra settings that I need to do in order to make Outlook Oauth2 work in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

We were able to fix the bug by adding `User.Read` into the `scopes`. Apparently, that's the only thing missing from all of this.